# How to check if there is a connection to a android wear from an app? Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, sony-smartwatch

In my application I want to display a message to the user if the user is connected to his smartwatch or not. 
I am trying to check if there is a connection from my device to the smartwatch, and I coudn't find an answer in the internet. How can I check it? Is the easiest way to do this is to send a message and check for an answer?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[NodeApi.getConnectedNodes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.html#getConnectedNodes(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) provides you a list of connected Android Wear nodes

If this list is empty (or while connecting the required `GoogleApiClient` to the [Wearable.API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Wearable.html#API) returns [API_UNAVAILABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#API_UNAVAILABLE) (such as in cases where the Android Wear app is not installed or the API level does not support Android Wear as per [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/tips-for-error-handling-with-android.html)) then no Wear device is attached.